# Why am I getting a 403?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, clickonce

I've published a `ClickOnce` application.

The application downloads and installs properly from `MyApplication/MyApplication.application`.

However, if they access `MyApplication/setup.exe` to automatically install the prerequisites and then run the application, they get a `403`.

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

In Handler Mappings, `cgi-exe` is disabled. I've added a module mapping as follows:

```
Name: setup.exe
Path: setup.exe
State: Enabled
Path type: unspecified
Handler: StaticFileModule
Entry type: Local
Access required by the handler: Script
Specify verbs to be handled: all verbs
[Unchecked] Invoke handler only if request is mapped to...
```

The application pool has `Full Control` on the folder and runs on the `Application Pool Identity`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reason in the IIS logs.

Thanks to Lex Li at the IIS forums.

Comment: @Downvoter. Is there some way that the answer can be improved? I did find the reason in the IIS logs. It can be different for different people. In my case it was URLScan.

Comment: I upvoted, because you took the time to update your question with an answer.  Thanks